# emulator crashes when trying to run my sample android app with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

SO im following  the "Android programming the big nerd ranch guide"

The fragment is :

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {

    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitleField;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;
    public CrimeFragment() {
    }
    public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCrime = new Crime();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container, false);

        mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mCrime.setmTitle(s.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getmDate().toString());
        mDateButton.setEnabled(false);

        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
        mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mCrime.setmSolved(isChecked);
            }
        });
return v;
    }
}
```

and when i run it it doesn't even start and crashes. this is the log message. I'm not sure whats causing it to crash as it builds successfully and doesn't seem to have any fatal errors that i can see. I've already tried cleaing the code too.

```
  criminalintent I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
    02-15 15:47:44.720 2132-2132/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent I/art: Late-enabling JIT
    02-15 15:47:44.821 2132-2132/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
    02-15 15:47:45.158 2132-2132/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent-2/lib/x86
    02-15 15:47:45.958 2132-2139/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.901ms
    02-15 15:47:46.301 2132-2132/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    02-15 15:47:46.303 2132-2132/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent, PID: 2132
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
   at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeActivity.onCreate(CrimeActivity.java:11)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
   at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeActivity.onCreate(CrimeActivity.java:11) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.Date.toString()' on a null object reference
   at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onCreateView(CrimeFragment.java:57)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
   at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeActivity.onCreate(CrimeActivity.java:11) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    02-15 15:48:02.267 2132-2139/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.298ms
    02-15 15:48:08.351 2132-2132/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2132 SIG: 9
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your date object is null at 57. line of Crime Fragment: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.Date.toString()' on a null object reference"

Comment: `mCrime.getmDate().toString()` crashes because `mCrime.getmDate()` is null

Comment: Applause for working through the book. I encourage you to practice interpreting the log statements. Any time you get a crash log like this, be sure to scan down for the `Caused by:` lines. The last one will be the source of the error. In your case @AdamVarhegyi has correctly pointed out the null pointer exception.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance guys! it ended up being to do with a few typos with my getters and setters. once again thank you : AdamVarhegyi , EpicPandaForce and @tir38